# Why the browser generate an empty option when using comparator in select option?

Tags: html

This HTML produces an empty option in the browser, how it could be? And how to handle this?

```html
<select name="comparator" id="comparator">
    <option value="=="> Equals (==) </option>
    <option value="&gt"> Greater Than (&gt) </option>
    <option value="&lt"> Less Than (&lt) <option>
    <option value="&gt="> Greater Than/Equal (&gt=) </option>
    <option value="&gt="> Less Than/Equal (&gt=) </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have an `<option>` instead of a `</option>` after the "Less Than (&lt)".

Comment: you can safely omit the `</option>` entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close this tag

```
 <option value="&lt"> Less Than (&lt) **<option>**




<select name="comparator" id="comparator">
    <option value="=="> Equals (==) </option>
    <option value="&gt"> Greater Than (&gt) </option>
    <option value="&lt"> Less Than (&lt) **<option>**
    <option value="&gt="> Greater Than/Equal (&gt=) </option>
    <option value="&gt="> Less Than/Equal (&gt=) </option>
</select>
```

Should be:

```
<select name="comparator" id="comparator">
    <option value="=="> Equals (==) </option>
    <option value="&gt"> Greater Than (&gt) </option>
    <option value="&lt"> Less Than (&lt) </option>
    <option value="&gt="> Greater Than/Equal (&gt=) </option>
    <option value="&gt="> Less Than/Equal (&gt=) </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Questions caused by typographical errors should be closed, not answered.